# Best way to convert Java SQL Date from yyyy-MM-dd to dd MMMM yyyy format

Tags: java, date, format

Is there a straightforward way of converting a Java SQL Date from format yyyy-MM-dd to dd MMMM yyyy format?

I could convert the date to a string and then manipulate it but I'd rather leave it as a Java SQL Date. at the time I need to do this, the data has already been read from the MySQL database so I cant do the change there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Object such as `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` (of which `java.sql.Date` is a subclass) don't have a format of themselves. You use a `java.text.DateFormat` object to display these objects in a specific format, and it's the `DateFormat` (not the `Date` itself) that determines the format.

For example:

```
Date date = ...;  // wherever you get this
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
String text = df.format(date);
System.out.println(text);
```

Note: When you print a `Date` object without using a `DateFormat` object, like this:

```
Date date = ...;
System.out.println(date);
```

then it will be formatted using some default format. That default format is however not a property of the `Date` object that you can change.

Comment: Thanks. I have done something similar to this where the dates are written to an arraylist in a servlet and then reformatted to strings. This arraylist is then set to a session variable and processed in a JSP.

Answer (score 6):

If it is for presentation you can use SimpleDateFormat straight away:

```
package org.experiment;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Dates {
    private static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Date oneDate = new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        System.out.println(df.format(oneDate));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what you mean by a "Java SQL Date". If you mean as in `java.sql.Date`, then it doesn't really *have* a string format... it's just a number. To format it *in* a particular way, use something like [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Alternatively, convert it to a [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) `DateTime`; Joda Time is a much better date and time API than the built-in one. For example, `SimpleDateFormat` isn't thread-safe.

(Note that a `java.sql.Date` has more precision than a normal `java.util.Date`, but it looks like you don't need that here.)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate()
             .format(
                 DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.LONG )
                                  .withLocale ( Locale.UK )
             )
```

> 11 May 2017

## Do not conflate date-time values with their textual representation

As others said, **a date-time object has *no* format**. Only strings generated from the object or parsed by the object have a format. But such strings are always separate and distinct from the date-time object.

## Use objects, not strings

Avoid using strings to communicate date-time values to/from your database. For date-time values, use date-time classes to instantiate date-time objects.

The very purpose of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) is to mediate the differences in types between your database and Java.

## Using java.time

The other Answers are outdated as they use the troublesome old legacy date-time classes or the venerable Joda-Time library. Both have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

If you have a [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) object in hand, convert to [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) by calling the new method [`toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--) added to the old class.

```
LocalDate ld = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ;
```

For [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) that comply with [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later, you can work directly with java.time types.

You seem to be interested in the date-only values. So use `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

- [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)
  myPStmt.setObject( … , myLocalDate )
- [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-)
  myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class )

To generate a string in your desired format, you could specify a custom formatting pattern. But I suggest letting java.time automatically localize.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example…

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );  // Today's date at this moment in that zone.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale ( Locale.UK );
String output = ld.format ( f );
```

> output: 11 May 2017

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).