# How do I format a java.sql.date into this format: "MM-dd-yyyy"?

Tags: java, date

I need to get a java.sql.date in the following format "MM-dd-yyyy", but I need it to stay a java.sql.date so I can put it into a table as date field.  So, it cannot be a String after the formatting, it has to end up as a java.sql.date object.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
java.util.Date 
today=new Date();
String date = formatter.format(today); 
Date todaydate = formatter.parse(date);
java.sql.Date fromdate = new java.sql.Date(todaydate.getTime());
java.sql.Date todate=new java.sql.Date(todaydate.getTime()); 
String tempfromdate=formatter.format(fromdate);
String temptodate=formatter.format(todate); 
java.sql.Date fromdate1=(java.sql.Date) formatter.parse(tempfromdate); 
java.sql.Date todate1=(java.sql.Date) formatter.parse(temptodate);
```

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178690/best-way-to-convert-java-sql-date-from-yyyy-mm-dd-to-dd-mmmm-yyyy-format

Comment: @user3758849 Edit the original question with the code, and include why/how it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Can you please check my code..i tried in many ways..cud'n come up with the exact output that is why am here. @shekharsuman

Comment: You either format a `Date` and get a `String`, or you use `Date` object as is. Your requirements do not make sense.

Answer (score 15):

You can do it the same way as a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) (since [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) is a sub-class of `java.util.Date`) with a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "MM-dd-yyyy");
int year = 2014;
int month = 10;
int day = 31;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1); // <-- months start
                                    // at 0.
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Output is the expected

> 10-31-2014

Comment: yes but when u format Date u will get the output only as String type.

Comment: @user3758849 That is what it means to format a Date. Which is another way of saying that Date(s) aren't String(s); or if you prefer, String(s) aren't Date(s).

Comment: yes i agree.but i could not check this formatted date which is in string and the database column which is in date. This is my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code i have convert today date. learn from it and try with your code

```
          Date today = new Date();

        //If you print Date, you will get un formatted output
        System.out.println("Today is : " + today);

        //formatting date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
        SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in MM-dd-yyyy format : " + date);

            Date date1 = formatter.parse(date);
    System.out.println(date1);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date1));
```

Comment: Did you check my code? Even i've converted today's date

Comment: java.util.Date today=new Date();
String date = formatter.format(today); 
Date todaydate = formatter.parse(date); Done it already. i need to pass the sql date to my query.

Comment: Very useful construction String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today); It helped me.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.util.Date today=new Date();
java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(today.getTime()); //your SQL date object
SimpleDateFormat simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
System.out.println(simpDate.format(date)); //output String in MM-dd-yyyy
```

Note that it does not matter if your date is in format mm-dd-yyyy or any other format, when you compare date (java.sql.Date or java.util.Date) they will always be compared in form of the dates they represent. The format of date is just a way of setting or getting date in desired format.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to just convert the date in the query to epoch before comparing.

```
SELECT date_column from YourTable where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) > ?;
```

Then, simply pass `date.getTime()` when binding value to `?`.

NOTE: The `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function is for MySQL. You'll find such functions for other databases too.

Comment: Sorry, no access to change the database column and its MS SQL server management studio.

Comment: You don't need to change the column, you just need to change the query

Comment: This is where i want to pass those dates from java. convert(date,XXXX) >=CAST (? AS date) and convert(date,XXXXX) <= CAST (? AS date)

Answer (score 0):

The `formatter.parse` will only give you a `java.util.Date` not a `java.sql.Date`

once you have a `java.util.Date` you can convert it to a `java.sql.Date` by doing

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date (normalDate.getTime ());
```

Also note that **no** dates have any built in format, it is in reality a class built on top of a number.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this in 2017 or later, the modern solution uses `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead of `java.sql.Date`. The latter is long outdated.

**Formatting your date**

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu", Locale.US);
    LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    String tempFromDate = fromDate.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(tempFromDate);
```

This prints something like

```
11-25-2017
```

**Don’t confuse your date value with its textual representation**

Neither a `LocalDate` nor a `java.sql.Date` object has any inherent format. So please try — and try hard if necessary — to keep the two concepts apart, the date on one side and its presentation to a user on the other.

It’s like `int` and all other data types. An `int` can have a value of 4284. You may format this into 4,284 or 4 284, 004284 or even into hex representation. This does in no way alter the `int` itself. In the same way, formatting your date does not affect your date object. So use the string for presenting to the user, and use `LocalDate` for storing into your database (a modern JDBC driver or other modern means of database access wil be happy to do that, for example through `PreparedStatement.setObject()`).

**Use explicit time zone**

Getting today’s date is a time zone sensitive operation since it is not the same date in all time zones of the world. I strongly recommend you make this fact explicit in the code. In my snippet I have used Asia/Kolkata time zone, please substitute your desired time zone. You *may* use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` for your JVM’s time zone setting, but please be aware that this setting may be changed under our feet by other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM, so this is fragile.