# Format java.sql.Date to dd-MMM-yy for setDate

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc

Is there a way to change to format of java.sql.date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-MMM-yy?

The code I have so

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Yes you can. Follow the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178690/best-way-to-convert-java-sql-date-from-yyyy-mm-dd-to-dd-mmmm-yyyy-format .  Just change the pattern as per your need.

Comment: Both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` are outmoded, troublesome old legacy classes. Use only java.time classes instead. `myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" ) )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a java.sql.date into this format: “MM-dd-yyyy”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320378/how-do-i-format-a-java-sql-date-into-this-format-mm-dd-yyyy). I know it’s not the same format, but I trust you can grap the idea and adapt it.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using the long outdated `Date` classes? Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

You can format java.sql.Date with java.text.SimpleDateFormat:

```
String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(new java.sql.Date(0));
```

Comment: The troublesome classes used here have been legacy for years, supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and Java 9, and back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 & Android.